# Compiling QJson statically into Qt Application (multiple declaration errors)

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, static-libraries

Has anyone had success compiling [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) statically into an application? I am trying to use QJson statically in my Qt application (Windows/Mac), meaning I'm trying to use the source files directly rather than compiling a DLL and using it. Is this possible? My program is producing lots of errors when I attempt to do it, mostly "multiple declaration" errors. They are seemingly related to having a method structure like this:

```
SerializerRunnable::SerializerRunnable(QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent),
      QRunnable(),
      d(new Private)
{
  qRegisterMetaType<QVariant>("QVariant");
}
SerializerRunnable::~SerializerRunnable()
{
  delete d;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "method structure"? I don't see anything unusual.

Comment: I just meant this is how things are declared in the *.cpp files. It seems OK to me also (method overloading?) but it seems to think things are being declared twice. I don't know what the issue is.

Comment: I think we'll need to see additional context and errors in order to help.

Comment: Sorry, that is about the best I can do. QJson is setup as a Qt project that will compile into a *.DLL. I thought it should be a simple as adding the source files into my project, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that's compiled into a DLL needs to **export** the functions and classes that it wants to expose to the outside world linking to it at runtime.

In this particular case that magic happens in `qjson_export.h`:

```
#ifndef QJSON_EXPORT_H
#define QJSON_EXPORT_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#ifndef QJSON_EXPORT
# if defined(QJSON_MAKEDLL)
   /* We are building this library */
#  define QJSON_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
# else
   /* We are using this library */
#  define QJSON_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
# endif
#endif

#endif
```

If you don't have `DEFINES += QJSON_MAKEDLL` in your `.pro` file then the compiler assumes that you are *using* a DLL, rather than compiling code, and gets confused when code that is marked as "defined elsewhere" by `Q_DECL_EXPORT` is, in fact, right there, and stupidly assumes it's being defined multiple times.

I hope that makes sense. :P

Comment: Ahh that works! Thank you very much. I was confused by QJSON_MAKEDLL and assumed that it would be making a DLL rather than compiling source into my result executable. I'm curious why you only need to define QJSON_MAKEDLL for Windows? Is it not also a shared library by default on Unix based systems?

Comment: I can't speak to this with any authority, but I would guess that it has something to do with the fact that all functions/classes/etc are public by default when building a shared library on Unix. But that doesn't explain why it would "work" when `Q_DECL_IMPORT` is clearly and explicitly declared in the absence of a `QJSON_MAKEDLL` when building the `.pro` file in a Unix environment... Maybe somebody else can shed some light on this.